# [kotlin]Mark function as suspendable

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I got following functions for making server calls

```
suspend fun <T: BaseResponse> processPost(post:Post):T? {
        val gson=Gson()
        val data=gson.toJson(post.reqData)
        val res= sendPost(data,post.script)
        Log.d("server","res:"+res.first)
        //process response here
        return null
}
private fun sendPost(data:String,url:String):Pair<String,Int> {
        //send data to server
}
```

In some cases `processPost` may enter into infinite loop(for instance to wait for access token refresh).Of course this code should never be run on the main thread.But when I mark this function as `suspend` IDE is highliting it as redundant.Its not big deal but I'm curious how then can I restrict function execution on the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have quite some learning on coroutines to do. It’s impossible to cover all you need to know in one single answer. That’s what tutorials are for. Anyway I will try to answer just the points you asked. It may not make sense before you learn the concepts, I’m sorry if my answer does not help.

Just like many other things, coroutines are **not magic**. If you don’t understand what something does, you cannot hope it has the properties you want. It may sound harsh but I want to stress that such mentality is a major cause of bugs.

---

If you just want the compiler/IDE to shut up about the redundant `suspend` modifier, you can simply add `@Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")` to the function. But you shouldn't, because the compiler knows better than you, at least for now.

---

You thought adding the suspend modifier can prevent the main thread from running the function, but that's not how it works.

```kotlin
@Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
suspend fun someHeavyComputation(): Result { // like your processPost function
    return ...
}


launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // this will run in the main thread and freeze the application
    val result = someHeavyComputation()
    messWithUi(result)
}
```

---

Now, the question is actually an example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). To prevent the computation from running in the main thread, you should use `withContext` to jump threads.

```kotlin
suspend fun someHeavyComputation() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    ... // this will be in a thread pool
}

launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // this submits the computation to the thread pool
    val result = someHeavyComputation()
    // then the rest of the coroutine is run in the main thread
    // when `result` is ready
    messWithUi(result)
}
```

---

> Doesn't running coroutine in the main thread freeze it unitl coroutine is finished?

Quite the contrary. One of the great things about coroutines is that you can write in direct style, run it on the main thread without blocking it. E.g.

```kotlin
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val result = makeAnHttpCall() // this suspend function can take a long time
    messWithUi(result) // changes to the UI has to be in the main thread
}
```

This is translated behind the scenes into something like

```kotlin
makeAnHttpCall(callback = { result ->
    runInMainThread {
        messWithUi(result)
    }
})
```

---

Further reading: [Blocking threads, suspending coroutines](https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761).

Comment: Thanks,I know all of that.Let me clarify my question.Suppose we have function with heavy calculations inside and it doesn't call any suspend functions.My aim is to restrict using this function anywhere beside coroutines.Ide thinks suspend is redundant there.Anyway I found acceptable workaround: add `kotlinx.coroutines.delay(0)` to my function.

Comment: You miss a great deal of the benefits if you do not launch coroutines in the main thread.

Comment: My coroutines are for network calls what do you mean by 'launching them in the main thread'?Probably this point I'm not quite got.Doesn't running coroutine in the main thread freeze it unitl coroutine is finished?

Comment: I added some elaboration, and a link for further reading. I hope it clears things up.